# Approach for generating a lot of REST API traffic

Tags: python, rest, testing

I am building a traffic generator to generate stateful REST traffic. My thought is to load up a canned web-based application and just try HTTP queries continuously. However, because I wish to deploy this on small VM's, it would ideal to not to host an actual web service, but some type of simulator. Is there a reference REST stress test server library available for users to write custom REST API wrappers?

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use Apache JMeter (http://jmeter.apache.org/) tool to generate HTTP queries to your application.

Comment: Sorry I had a typo in my question. I don't have enough room to host a full web service. I'm looking for something that I can use to simulate a web service without running one.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understand, however if you don't have enough room on VM you can run the test from local machine, but keep in mind that you won't be able to generate high load (internet connection capacity, just one machine, ...).

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look at [Locust](http://locust.io/) which is an open source load generation tool, written in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the load you want to conduct:

- Small load (i.e. from one machine) - [SoapUI](http://soapui.org/) (see [Using SoapUI for load testing](https://www.soapui.org/getting-started/load-testing.html)). Also SoapUI doesn't produce very good results to analyse.
- Immense load (i.e. from multiple machines) - [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) (see [Testing SOAP/REST Web Services Using JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter)). JMeter can be launched from a single machine as well and it provides better readable and understandable results especially with [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You may try to [Yandex Tank](https://github.com/yandex/yandex-tank). It could use different load generators (default phantom or jmeter) and provide very useful features in load management and reporting.